# Synchronizing table column widths between tables

Tags: jquery, html-table

I'm trying to come up with a solution to synchronize the column widths of multiple tables, where the column widths are not fixed, but widths are decided in the same way they are for a single table without width specified. Perhaps with the ability to declare some columns as desiring to shrink to the minimum width, and others as desiring to expand to the maximum width.

I've not come up with a good solution at all. I initially attempted to synchronize the widths using jQuery during onResize... but I can't come up with anyway to set the width without interfering with the size calculation.

JQuery (DOM in general) seems to provide no way to return the desired minimum width of a container, as most other UI frameworks do (ahh, HTML, how I love you, not). If I had this ability, I'd lay out the columns myself. Wouldn't be that hard.

Any ideas?

For instance, I'd like the column widths of these tables to be synchronized, regardless of the content in the individual cells.

```
<table>
  <tr><td>Col1</td><td>Col2</td><td>Col3</td><td>Col4</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Col1</td><td>Col2</td><td>Col3</td><td>Col4</td></tr>
</table>
<table>
  <tr><td>Col1</td><td>Col2</td><td>Col3</td><td>Col4</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Col1</td><td>Col2</td><td>Col3</td><td>Col4</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: can you post an example that would highlight what exactly is the problem? in my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/deathApril/Ls27y/), JQuery's width + HTML5 data-* attribute work just fine..

Comment: wasabi, I see that you have a lot of [unresolved questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/413967/wasabi?tab=questions) in your history. Please take the time to either accept an answer or follow up with any deficiencies in existing answers so they can be wrapped up. Thanks.

Comment: Jerome: Please consider marking my answer as correct if it answers your question. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a function to set all table column widths to be the same as the widest version of the column in any table.

```
function AlignMultipleTables(class_name)
{
    // Align tables with the specified class so that all columns line up across tables.

    // Find the max width of each column across all tables. Only look at 'th' or 'td' cells in the first row of each table.
    var col_widths = [];
    $("." + class_name).each(function(index, element) {
        $(element).find("tr:first th, tr:first td").each(function(index2, element2) {
            col_widths[index2] = Math.max(col_widths[index2] || 0, $(element2).width());
        });
    });

    // Set each column in each table to the max width of that column across all tables.
    $("." + class_name).each(function(index, element) {
        $(element).find("tr:first th, tr:first td").each(function(index2, element2) {
            $(element2).width(col_widths[index2]);
        });
    });
}
```

Give all tables a class of something like "align-to-widest" and then call the function like this:

```
AlignMultipleTables("align-to-widest");
```

See my [jsfiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/8umbd/)